# String to number, including non number characters

Tags: javascript

Is there a native method to convert a string that includes non number characters to a number in one pass, without resorting to `str.substring()` and then `parseInt()`?

For example if I would want to convert the string `x1` to `1`.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Can you confirm you're only interested in integers ? And do you want to handle strings without digits ? How ?

Comment: I always expect strings with digits. It doesn't need to cover every possible scenario, it's a simple problem and requires a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not one native function, but it's simple enough for positive integers:

```
var number = +str.match(/\d+/);
```

If you want to accept a dot and a sign, you may use

```
var number = +str.match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?/);
```

Note that this makes `0` if there's no digit in the string.

Comment: Very useful answer !